# How to kubernetes "kubectl apply" does not update existing deployments

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a .NET-core web application. This is deployed to an Azure Container Registry. I deploy this to my Azure Kubernetes Service using

> kubectl apply -f testdeployment.yaml

with the yaml-file below

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myweb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myweb
        image: mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myweb:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-registry-key
```

This works splendid, but when I change some code, push new code to container and run the

> kubectl apply -f testdeployment

again, the AKS/website does not get updated, until I remove the deployment with

> kubectl remove deployment myweb

**What should I do to make it overwrite whatever is deployed?** I would like to add something in my yaml-file. (Im trying to use this for continuous delivery in Azure DevOps).

Comment: Did you try not using latest but the version in the image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is imagePullPolicy. The default is ifNotPresent which means that the latest version will not be pulled.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myweb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myweb
        image: mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myweb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-registry-key
```

To ensure that the pod is recreated, rather run:

```
kubectl delete -f testdeployment && kubectl apply -f testdeployment
```

Comment: Even better! ...Yes, that what I was looking for :o)

Comment: ..Ehr.. .too hasty ... didnt work... and according to this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images, "Always" should be default if you refer to container:latest  and omit imagePullPolicy...so it should already be "Always"... I also need to remove :latest for it to work as wished... (alhough your right in theory/spec). Could you please update your sample without :latest, then I can set it as correct, to help others

Comment: (works with or without imagePullPolicy, it more depends on :latest or not)

Comment: Updated as per the comment above

Comment: if the deployment definition does not change, it still won't apply anything. it would pull the "latest" version again, if it has to recreate the pod, but not on `kubectl apply`

Answer (score 13):

`kubectl` does not see any changes in your deployment yaml file, so it will not make any changes. That's one of the problems using the `latest` tag.

Tag your image to some incremental version or build number and replace `latest` with that tag in your CI pipeline (for example with `envsubst` or similar). This way `kubectl` knows the image has changed. And you also know what version of the image is running. The `latest` tag could be any image version.

Simplified example for Azure DevOps:

```
# <snippet>
        image: mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myweb:${TAG}
# </snippet>
```

Pipeline YAML:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    variables:
    - name: TAG
      value: $(Build.BuildId)
    steps:
    - script: |
        envsubst '${TAG}' < deployment-template.yaml > deployment.yaml
      displayName: Replace Environment Variables
```

Alternatively you could also use another tool like [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) (different syntax: `#{TAG}#`).

Comment: I added an example for Azure DevOps pipelines.

Comment: I guess this is a better solution, but if I have to choose the correct answer to my question I had to be Daniel Lee.  I hope I dont cause too much confusion

Comment: the problem is, that it's wrong. when you use the `latest` tag, `imagePullPolicy` is `Always` by default.

Comment: Yes, I agree, by looking at the documentation. However, I did use the :latest-tag to begin with,when I originally wrote the question.

Comment: right, and ommitting the tag behaves exactly the same. latest, no-tag, imagePullPolicy: Always = all the same thing. re-run your example and you'll find out that nothing changed if your yaml didn't change. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images

Comment: These are the results Ive got. (1) using ":latest" -> image was NOT pulled. (even though it said so in docs, I know (2) using ".latest" and imagePullPolicy : Always -> Same as (1). (3) **Not** using latest -> always overwrite. This is what I need for my development

Comment: @Cowborg the answer by Markus is correct. 
You can use the :latest tag. What it will do is always overwrite your image in the container registry. But if there is already a deployment running and you changed nothing in the deployment file your pod will not be recreated. (One solution is to delete the pod and it will pull down the latest pod again as i suggested in my answer below).
The better solution is to use something dynamic as MarkusDresch suggested. Only downside is your container registry would be very big after sometime.

Comment: Totally agree with you (and the Markuses) (except that I didnt get that result for :latest)

Answer (score 0):

First delete the deployment config file by running below command on the relative path of the deployment file.

```
kubectl delete -f .\deployment-file-name.yaml
```

earlier I used to get

> deployment.apps/deployment-file-name unchanged

meaning the deployment file remains cached.
It happens while you're fixing some errors / typos on the deployment YAML & the config got cached once the error got cleared.

Only a `kubectl delete -f .\deployment-file-name.yaml` could remove the cache.

Later you can do the deployment by

```
kubectl apply -f .\deployment-file-name.yaml
```

Sample yaml file as follows :

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: deployment-file-name
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: myservicename
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: platformservice
spec:
containers:
- name: platformservice
image: /platformservice:latest